# why there is a horizontal scroll bar in my chrome even after using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollbar, responsive

I cant find the reason of a horizontal scroll bar in my chrome when width of screen is more than 1200px. You can see the live demo of my site [here](http://www.a2ztechbay.com/ismr/)

Answer (score 0):

For full-width use .container-fluid 
For a container user .container

```
<div class="container"> //container
    <div class="row">
        //your content
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid"> //full width
    <div class="row">
       //your full-width content
    </div>
</div>
```